# How to center a header based on content length?

Tags: html, css

I would like to perfectly center the header of my page in its body. What this means to me is:

1. Finding the size of the content in the div and setting the div to the size of the content, and then.
2. Centering that div within the body.

From my understanding, `margin: 0 auto` should center a div, and `display: inline-block` will set the size of the div to the size of its content. I’ve tried this, I’m not sure why this isn't working—it seems like these two attributes don’t play nicely with each other. Could someone take a look at my HTML/CSS and see if they know what’s wrong?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1> Hi There! </h1>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this css:

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SL8up/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `display: inline-block;`:

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Just change `display` to `block`:

```
h1 {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 150px;
}

<body>
    <div class="header"><h1> Hi There! </h1></div>
</body>
```

Full HTML with working inline CSS here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
h1 {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hi There! </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! One of the reasons I don't see this working is the `width: 150px;` part. For the site that I'm trying to center the header in, the content within the `h1` tag is dynamically generated, so I won't know the width of it ahead of time, which is why I was trying `display: inline-block`. Could I still center the header as I described in the OP without setting the width to a fixed value?

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Do you have any recommendations for how I could center the header? I guess JS?